# Advice for non-native English speakers

Tags: support, faq, low-quality-posts, quality-improvement

I'm not a native speaker of English, but I want to ask a question on Stack Overflow.  When I finish typing it out, my question gets a lot of downvotes and comments about the grammar being wrong.

How can I fix this so that my questions don't get viewed so negatively?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

If you aren't a native English speaker, here are some general guidelines that you can follow in order to improve the quality of your posts and the community's reaction to them.

(If you *are* a native English speaker, you should probably *also* be following these rules!)

Please don't be intimidated—perfection is not required! There is an extensive reviewing/moderating mechanism on this site designed to help improve both questions and answers. But putting in the extra effort when writing your post can make some of that work *significantly easier* for the rest of us.

---

1. **The word "I" is always capitalized in English.**

   Incorrect → "How can i install"
   Correct   → "How can I install"
2. **All sentences begin with a capital letter.**

   Incorrect → "how can I install a jar into the Tomcat classpath"
   Correct   → "How can I install a jar into the Tomcat classpath?"
3. **If you ask a question, end it with a single question mark (<kbd>?</kbd>).**
4. **If you write a statement, end it with a single period (or dot, <kbd>.</kbd>) (also known as "full stop").**
5. **Don't use the abbreviations that you might see in a text/SMS message or a chat room.**

   Incorrect → "how r u doing this"
   Correct   → "How are you doing this?"
6. **Ensure a clear, readable layout of the text: code blocks, usage of paragraphs, etc.**
7. **Do not overuse capital letters, but do use them appropriately.**

   Incorrect → "javascript" or "JAVASCRIPT"
   Correct   → "JavaScript"
8. **Use apostrophes correctly when using shortened forms (contractions).**

   Incorrect → "Im" or "isnt"
   Correct   → "I'm" or "isn't"

   The rule is this: in a contraction, the omitted letters are replaced by an apostrophe. So, instead of "is not", you could write "isn't", where the apostrophe is used in place of the letter "o".
9. **Use a space *after*, but not *before*, punctuation marks (e.g., periods, commas, question marks, exclamation points, etc.).**

   Incorrect → "Why does this happen?I have tried everything!Nothing works." or "Why does this happen ? I have tried everything ! Nothing works ."
   Correct   → "Why does this happen? I have tried everything! Nothing works."
10. **Announce lists and enumerations with *only* a colon <kbd>:</kbd>**.

    Incorrect → "For example-" or "See below:-"
    Correct   → "For example:" or "See below:"
11. **Do not use inline code formatting for emphasis. Use bold or italics instead and use them sparingly.**

    Incorrect → "My code doesn't work `even though the file is available`."
    Correct   → "My code doesn't work **even though the file is available**."

Comment: Native speakers (***especially*** American) have their own set of problems: [Run-on sentences](https://twitter.com/PeterMortensen/status/1199839973215739907) and homonyms/homophones (e.g., *["you're"/"your"](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-You%27re-and-Your)*, *["there"/"their"/"they're"](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-There,-Their-and-They%27re)*, *["than"/"then"](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Than-and-Then)*, *"affect"/"effect"*, *["were"/"where"/"we're"](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Where,-Were-and-We're)*, *"alot"/"allot"/"a lot"*, and *"definitely"/"definately"*").  Perhaps cover that as well?

Comment: My favorites: "Find info bellow:" and "This doe snot ...", for nicely passing all spell checking.

Comment: 11. **Consider using a tool to get help with spelling and grammar**.

Two examples that have free versions, and are available as browser extensions:

* [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/)
* [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/)

Answer (score 33):

As a non-English speaker, I feel like if you can't at least formulate a question properly so that it doesn't strike viewers as poorly written, then you should work on your English skills before asking questions on Stack Overflow. If you have any particular questions on learning the English language, you can check out our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

The purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions with high quality answers. High quality requires a clear description. Therefore posts that are unclear because of faulty English risk rejection (down votes and close votes).

Comment: This. You can even disregard SO, it is absolutely worth the time and resources for any engineer to take English lessons. Put it on your resume/CV and benefit from it even more. Go on vacation to foreign countries and have a reasonable chance of being able to communicate.

Comment: Although I agree your opinion, unfortunately the mainstream opinion, on my experience, doesn't. Anyways, more as 90% of the posts with terrible spelling is crap, and they can be closed because of they are crap.

Comment: Now I agree your opinion. And, many of native English speakers are writing on such a lazy way. I think, they should simply take some courses in an elementary school for adults, instead of distributing degeneracy on the Internet.

Answer (score 32):

There are a number of errors I see made when reading posts on Stack Overflow, and it may be helpful for a few of them to be covered here. We do try to make allowances for people whose first language is not English, but any adjustments made by the non-native speaker are very much appreciated.

### Tense

I often encounter statements in this style:

> I am having the following error

This sounds rather awkward in English, and it is much better to simply say:

> I have the following error

*Aside: I have received feedback in the comments that the first construction does not sound awkward to the American ear. I would much appreciate feedback from other US-based commenters on this point, so I can improve this section. Thanks.*

### Continuation punctuation

Often an asker will want to indicate that a sentence refers to material directly after it. We often see constructs of these forms:

> Please see my Java code :
> *(space-prefixed colon)*
>
> My log cat is as follows :-
> *(a colon-hyphen construct, or sometimes even hyphen-colon)*
>
> Here is a screenshot of the issue...
> *(an ellipsis)*
>
> The error I am receiving is ::
> *(somewhat rarer - double or even triple colon constructs)*

The best approach here is a single colon without a space prefix; removing the space is helpful, because it prevents the colon mark from being orphaned by a line break. Some languages (such as French) encourage a space prefix; if you really must use a space here, use the non-breaking space entity `&nbsp;`. However, don't be surprised if it gets lost in a subsequent edit!

### Politeness

Readers are, in general, most grateful for indications of politeness, but it's worth bearing in mind that ordinary expressions of civility in one language can sound obsequious in another, especially in the context of asking for help.

For example, these are all unnecessary in native English:

- Referring to people as "Sir" in the comments (especially since it may be based on incorrect gender assumptions)
- When offering thanks in advance, referring to the "precious time" or "precious replies" of readers who assist.
- We tend to edit out "Thanks in advance" anyway simply for reasons of brevity.

On a related note, there is no need to explicitly request help, since this is sometimes read as a form of begging. You're on a help site, so it is very clear you are posting in order to obtain help. For example, all of these can be removed:

- Please help
- Please help me
- Please help me out
- Please help me out of this

### Common mis-spellings

We try not to fuss over minor misspellings, but nevertheless you may find your post being accepted more readily if it is readable. Using your browser's spell-checker can help a great deal, if you can install an English one.

One word I see misspelled a great deal is "alot" (currently ~27,000 instances of this on the main site). This should be two words, "a lot"; the contracted form has slipped into common usage, but it is still incorrect.

We also see "im" or "Im" from time to time - in this case the word you're after is probably "I'm", which is a contraction of "I am". The apostrophe makes the word *much* more readable.

Text-speak has been mentioned elsewhere, and I would include within that category elements of abbreviated slang: we see a lot of *wanna* for "want to" and *gonna* for "going to". These are fine for chatrooms and your social media, not so for posts here.

### Culture-specific wording

There are a number of words that are not known in all English speaking territories, so either avoid them if you can, or alternatively explain them:

- "Fortnight", meaning a two week period, is not well known in the United States;
- "Doubt", meaning a question, tends to be specific to India; so if you would normally say "I have a doubt", then "I have a question" would be easier to understand, though given it does not convey anything useful, it is better just to remove it completely;
- "Lakh" and "Crore" are [Indian words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system) for large numbers: one hundred thousand and ten million respectively.
- If you refer to "dollar" as a unit of currency, it may be appropriate for you to indicate whether you mean the American (USD), Canadian (CAD), Australian (AUD) or other
  currency type. No, the US dollar is not the default. Also, if you use the dollar sign ($), it should go before the amount ($12.34, not 12.34$).

Comment: So I am not an native English speaker. And I use browsers spell check, but the point on topic you might be interested in `autocorrect` and spell check that doesn't cross languages. Most of my "I"s are lowercase (not intentionally) since in Slavic language group vowels also have meaning. ( 'a' as `ow that / but`,'i' as `and`,'o' as `about`,'u' as `in`) and Serbian for example has 2 written styles ( cyrillic and latinic ) and some use latinic as their primary style. Which confuses autocorrect a lot. So autocorrect and spell check often switch between English and Slavic several times in sentence.

Comment: Another thing to add, is it is easy to switch languages in your head, but it is very difficult to switch languages in your sentence and in your mind. For example Slavis use capital letters to show words or objects of importance. So language names are written with lowercase letters, but language groups are capitalised ( showing their uniqueness ). Also some languages are SVO (subject verb object) , SOV,VSO ... and this becomes even more difficult if person is bilingual or trilingual. I often unwillingly switch between German and English in how i construct sentence.

Comment: Also English isn't always American-English or British-English. There are also African-English, Slavic-English, Shino-Tibetan English and etc. If you think that English has become global language without any standard deviation, you are wrong. African languages as Twi or Ashanti ( among others) have injected their specific elements to English making it unique. Anyone who has spoken with a person over internet that isn't tied to Indo European language group can verify this.

Comment: We agree on variations of English, @Danilo - we get British English, American English and Indian English a lot here. We probably get others, but I haven't yet discerned another major group on Stack Overflow yet.

Comment: @Danilo: your other points are most interesting, but the point I was making was that folks who do not have English as a first language can install an English spell-checker. The one I have in Firefox seems to recognise some case issues (JavaScript) but not the personal pronoun (I). However, if obvious misspellings are caught because the question author made an effort, that's great - it saves editing work, and helps readers wanting to assist the author.

Comment: These comments were not meant as argument against or for your (plural in this case) question or anything similar. It says that I can't add more answers, and I should edit existing ones. But existing ones are perfectly ok, I just wanted to point out some causes in order for some mod that reads this knows that sometimes mistakes aren't intentional and to try and avoid grammar natzi rises which could alienate people who were thought "broken" English from the start.

Comment: @Danilo: I think non-native English speakers can ask and expect some tolerance from native speakers. However, there is nothing wrong with people wanting to correct grammar - if grammar is already poor in a question then a non-native reader will struggle with it all the more.

Comment: My last remark in this thread is that I would discourage you from making frivolous comparisons to fascism. People wanting good grammar and spelling have nothing to do with the (historical) far right, and it is not healthy to normalise that insult.

Comment: I highly recommend Grammarly.  You don't necessary have to use the browser add-on (or make a habit of turning it off on other websites).  I mention this fact, some might say, their Terms of Service is overly broad in data collection.  However, it's a great tool, and their are others that exist.

Comment: *Definitely* is definitely misspelt [a lot more](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#definitely) than *a lot* —often as *definately*.

Comment: I do not consider “Thanks in advance” a mark of politeness. I mean, real politeness. Simply because it implies that you just don’t let the choice to do, or not do, what you’ve asked to the person.
I wonder in which language/culture it may be?