# The percentage of non-English speakers

Tags: discussion, languages

As the non-English native speaker, I'd like to ask you how many people are the same like me, having the English language as the secondary one (you can clearly see I am not from UK).

I feel there are majority of people from the English speaking country. My guess comes from lots of answers/questions that are really smooth and understandable to read.

Does exist the demographic statistics of people here, where do they come from and what languages do they speak? Or at least the percentage amount of the English native speakers?

Comment: ".. lots of answers/questions that are really smooth and understandable to read" - did you also look at the Edit history of these?  Also keep in mind that "Native English speaking" does not automatically mean "writes good text".

Comment: @RadLexus Yep, I am aware this fact :) It is still the proof of people skilled in the English language.

Comment: @RadLexus That's so true. I am an avid editor, and from the stuff that I edit, I would assume that only 1% of SO speaks English (I know the number must be higher than that). I will sometimes see people apologize for their "poor English" and I laugh because they clearly haven't been around to see some of the stuff that gets posted by people with English as a first language.

Comment: The funny thing is [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/2564301) in "Advice for non-native English speakers" often applies to native speakers as well. But the fact is that SO is for *programmers* - sticklers for detail, extending all the way to "being clear in your documentation". I suspect the same happens on sister sites such as "English Language & Usage" - "wot means 'x'" will quickly be edited into "What is the meaning of 'x'?"

Comment: @RadLexus I've edited that CW to include that. I think I'd probably fit in at EL&U; I might consider joining.

Comment: @Nikolas Once I've seen some stat, maybe here or on the MSE. The important thing is: we have roughly equal proportion of users from 1) USA 2) EU 3) all other. USA people are mostly native English, EU people are mostly not, and also the others are not. -> The sum is that I would estimate the percentage of the non-English speakers to about 70%.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does exist the demographic statistics of people here, where do they come from and what languages do they speak?

No. We don't collect that information.

Comment: Is it due the fact it's a kind of personal information or it's because of this information is unnecessary?

Comment: A bit of both. We never asked for this data, and we don't believe in collecting data just for collecting it. We do have _some_ information gotten from people who participated in [our survey](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016), but it is not possible to know how representative it is.

Comment: Yep, the survey seems to be a thing I have been looking for. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis You can also check out [Language Learners](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/). A number of SO users also belong to that site to help hone their English skills.

Comment: You have probably have same log from the user IPs about the different activities (voting, posting). Then the whois database can be a good estimation about the first language.