# Using abbreviations like "msg", "req"

Tags: discussion, edits, writing-style

I sometimes see abbreviations like "msg", "req" for message and request. They are commonly used on the internet, and I believe everyone knows what do they mean.

Should we use that?

Should I edit posts containing that?

I saw these advises [Advice for non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/), but this is not about technical abbreviations.

Comment: No - edit it out. It's not as if you're paying per character. The same goes for "u", "ur", "plz", and so on.

Comment: for the sake of clarity, yeah... edit these out. It can only cause confusion, for the added benefit of what? 5 chars left out?

Comment: I'd add that "msg" and "req" generally aren't technical abbreviations, but merely abbreviations of technical terms.

Comment: y u thk ev1 noz wut dis mean?

Answer (score 7):

Expanding relatively common abbreviations like "msg" and "req" improves readability a little.

I wouldn't edit a post if those were the only changes I was going to make, especially if the post is not recent (because editing would bump the post on the front page). However, if I were making a more substantial edit, I would certainly include those changes.

Comment: If a user has the edit privilege, I see no problem with making such edits regardless of the age of the post. There is always something else that can be improved with a post, but if a user with more than 3000 reputation finds themselves in the imaginary situation where a post is riddled with txt-spk nonsense and nothing else that can be improved, they should have no qualms about correcting that.

Comment: @TinyGiant Fair enough. If a post is **riddled** with abbreviations rather than just having one or two, I think that tilts the balance more towards making the edit.