# what does mean for proposed yesterday by an anonymous user?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, anonymous-user

Actually this question https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18215894 edited by `community`. So why here we showing information like

> **proposed yesterday by an anonymous user**

But I can see other area's like if community user has edited a question, then we can see community user name under the question as like

**edited May 23 at 12:38**

**Community♦**
**1**

> Why SO showing `**Community♦ 1**`  in main screen and showing `anonymous user` in edit  suggested screen in that question? is there any relation between them?

Comment: That the edit was proposed by an anonymous user tells you that the edit was proposed by an anonymous user.  What about that don't you understand?  Do you not know what an anonymous user is?

Comment: Anyone on the internet can propose changes. If they don't have a Stack Overflow account, it is recorded as 'anonymous', and moderators can see the IP address. When the suggested edit is *accepted*, then the resulting edit is attributed to Community, the catch-all system account.

Comment: Nope. I am asking about **why you are showing `community`  in main screen and showing `anonymous user` in edit  suggested screen**?

Comment: @RameshRajendran The edit is suggested by an anonymous user.  The edit is applied by the community user.

Comment: Related Meta.SE link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194252/what-is-an-anonymous-user-capable-of

Comment: You may read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) to improve your English skills.

Answer (score 20):

Anyone on the internet can suggest edits. When someone without a Stack Overflow account does this, then the resulting *suggested edit* is recorded as *anonymous* (but moderators can see the IP address).

When the suggested edit is *accepted*, the suggestion results in an actual change, a revision to the post. That resulting revision is attributed to Community. That's because all revisions on the site must have a valid user account associated with them, so Community is 'blamed'. We don't *need* to record that the change came from an anonymous user now, because that is already recorded in the suggestion.

Also, it was the *Stack Overflow community* that accepted the change; as we can't attribute the change to any other user, the Community user is a good fit.

So a *suggestion* is a separate thing from the actual change made to the post, and since it is separate it can have different information associated with it.