# How to advise questioners to write standard English?

Tags: discussion, questions, english

What would be a brief, polite, constructive way to advise questioners to write standard English?

For additional information, details and examples optionally follow.

**DETAILS AND EXAMPLES**

I ask because it is not always obvious to me whether a questioner

- has imperfect command of English as a second language,
- is cavalier or impertinent,
- has misjudged the moderate level of technical formality typical of good Stack Overflow Q&A, or
- suffers from a combination of the three.

What is obvious to me is that the most upvoted, most often viewed Q&A in the archive is written, or is at any rate edited, in reasonably standard technical English style. Therefore, questions written in standard English in the first place are appreciated, at least by me.

Example:

> i have a problem about javascript . i cant put js tag into double quote. My problem is something else but solves with this simple example . how can i fix it ?

To me, this example looks like weak English as a second language, yet does anyone who has received a mere few hours of English instruction not know that the pronoun *I* is to be capitalized? Maybe someone does not know this, but if the writer of the example knew, then weak English as a second language cannot wholly excuse a lack of care in composing the question. On the other hand, if the writer of the example did not know, then he or she is still leaving a mess for one of our editors to clean up.

Perhaps a mere few hours of English instruction do not suffice to contribute constructively to Stack Overflow. Fluent English is not required, but it seems to me that one can expect a moderately low, minimum level of technical English competence as a prerequisite to engage here. Otherwise, it would seem impossible for us to manage the site at all.

Another example:

> Hi please can someone tell me how i can achieve this type of image animation.

One could just silently downvote but, in cases like this, as feedback, I would prefer to give a reason.

One could alternately edit the question, of course, but editing takes time. If it wasn't worth the questioner's time to compose a proper question in the first place, then how is it worth mine? Is it not more constructive for me rather to leave a brief comment and move on?

If the questioner needs instruction in English, [that isn't my field.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

On the other hand, though I wish to be brief, I do not wish to be impolite. Moreover, as you know, in writing, impoliteness can be perceived when not intended. I would like to avoid the mishap if I can.

How do you handle this?

**REFERENCE**

My question seeks advice Stack Overflow *answerers* can heed, but see also [this related question,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291362/1275653) which seeks advice Stack Overflow *questioners* can heed.

Comment: I hope that I have made few English mistakes while writing! In view of the subject, English mistakes would be embarrassing, but despite best care mistakes will creep in. Let me know.

Comment: How about editing such posts? Editing is supported with the [Magic Editor](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/Magic%E2%84%A2Editor.user.js) script that tries to solve 80% of common issues so you can spend  your time of fixing the value of the post.

Comment: Language mistakes are (as long as the question is understandable) no reason to close vote. I also believe that down-votes due to missing language skills are suboptimal (again, as long as the question is clear enough to be understood).

Comment: @BDL I have removed mention of votes to close. Good point.

Comment: Why worry about grammar in second example? The premise of the question itself fits into "too broad" category to begin with. If grammatical errors are a pet peeve...edit or just move on

Comment: "but it seems to me that one can expect a moderately low, minimum level of technical English competence as a prerequisite to engage here" - Well said, although you can leave out the "moderately low" and still say the same ;)

Answer (score 10):

Your first example is easily solved by closing with the MCVE close reason.  Your second example is easily solved by closing as "Too Broad."

If you really want to give them advice, I usually say something in the comments along these lines:

> Your question is difficult to understand.  I suggest you have someone proofread your questions before you post them.

Comment: Rather than immediately reply, I have been thinking about your answer. Your answer is practically useful and is appreciated to this extent, for your answer concisely explains an existing Stack Overflow norm. One wishes to adhere to norms. This is why I have asked. However, the norm in this instance is in my opinion bad. (I have not said that you are bad. The *norm* is bad. I will explain.)

Comment: The total of up- and downvotes is not all that interesting on a question like this. That the question has several upvotes—despite that the total has buried the question so that comparatively few have even seen it—should tell us something. A significant number of Stack Overflow answerers may feel disrespected by questions written in conspicuously bad English. These answerers may be unimpressed by a blanket excuse of English as a second language. These answerers may resent being asked to clean up English messes left repeatedly by newcomers who lack a stake in the community.

Comment: What the norm you have concisely explained does is this: it asks answerers who resent what they perceive to be abuse to conceal the reason they dislike a question. So the newcomer earns downvotes yet never finds out clearly why. We riddle the newcomer, who does not know our ways. To avoid offending our own twisted norms, you and I can invent plausible reasons to close questions we secretly dislike, but does this help, really? My view is that this norm probably ought to change.

Comment: Whether the norm will indeed change is, of course, not for me to say.