# Why were my comments requesting clarification of a question deleted by a moderator?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

I made some comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382431/show-age-of-user), but they disappeared. I know that they were successfully posted, but then, after some time, they disappeared.

Is this a bug, or were they deleted by a moderator? If so, why?

Comment: Comments disappear all the time due to being flagged and removed by moderators.

Comment: Or just users flagging them as "not needed".

Comment: Your comments about the OP's grammar would have made more sense as the edit reason.

Comment: @CodeGray I was not aware that they were deleted by a moderator. You have totally changed the question.

Comment: @BSMP If the grammatical errors were in the title or the main text of the question, I could have edited it, but since it was part of the code, which would in turn become the ouput of the code, I could not edit it. Editing it would change the OP's intention (although it is wrong).

Comment: @sawa Comments can't be deleted by other beings than moderators, with the exception of autodeletion when flagging thanks and other smallish edge cases of multiple flags on comments. Not sure if that is intended as some kind of "defense" for posting it thrice, but it is rather poor...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Right. And the edit by Code Gray excludes that possibility.

Comment: Technically, they can, @Felix. Comments matching certain patterns will be automatically deleted after being flagged by one user, and they’ll show up as having been deleted by the flagger. Anyway, regarding my edit, I didn’t change the question. I clarified the title to reflect what actually happened and to make searching easier. It’s OK that you didn’t know this at the time you asked the question. The asker often doesn’t have all the facts; that’s why we have edits. (BTW, I don’t get pinged when you misspell my name.)

Comment: Oh... til. We can has delete comments! I never really thought of who was owning the deletion when flags auto delete comments.

Comment: I mean when you made [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55382431/3) you could have put those comments in the edit summary. You were making most of the same changes to the regular text anyway, it would have made sense there.

Comment: upvoted. Because I'm glad you ask this question, trying to understand what happends.
I believe that this is just a miss understanding: 
Seeing that your comment were not there you say the same thing again.
But the whole script give a really different feeling. I had my 50c of it in a answer.
I cannot make it fit into a comment.

Comment: You have very right! Note, these people can't ever reach high rep, and in their short existence they are on continuous pressure to at least try to emulate a near-literacy. The best what you can do: **maximize this pressure as you can**, on all possible ways - but don't allow them to shock you. Don't waste your nerves to them. Vote to down, close, del, vote always negatively, exterminate them with your votes, but don't waste your time and nerves to them!

Comment: You can also combine these with fair advices by linking [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291362/1783163) meta post. Also "polite comments" can be useful, but note, it is very dangerous since the new CoC (note, I've collected once a yearlong suspension for "insulting" these people, far before the new CoC (not on the SO)).

Answer (score 41):

I'm glad you brought this up. Moderators deleted *three* of your comments on that question in response to flags, all of which said *exactly the same thing*:

> What is your question?

Now, on the face, there's nothing wrong with that comment. It doesn't violate any of our Code of Conduct policies, and it isn't rude. However, it conveys very little information, so it's not a very *useful* comment.

That's why your first attempt to leave this comment got deleted by another moderator. It was immediately followed by another comment from you that *did* convey useful information, rendering it superfluous:

> Your issue is not clear. What do you mean by the age for a year? Are all users born on the moment the year changes to a new year?

For unknown reasons, you decided to post the:

> What is your question?

comment again. That's where I came in, handling a flag on that comment pointing out that this same comment had already been deleted once.

Again, seeing as how the comment conveyed no meaningful information *and* you had already left another comment that *did* provide that information, I deleted it.

The third time's the charm, of course, so you posted this same comment *again*, right after posting a bunch of noisy comments critiquing the poster's English skills. (These would otherwise have been passable comments, if it weren't for the fact that you separated them out into three different comments, substantially increasing the noise volume on that question.)

The third attempt to post the *exact same useless comment* got another flag, this time asking a moderator to escalate because it had already been flagged twice and deleted. I deleted it but didn't want to waste my time escalating. I was hoping that you'd give up.

In the interest of transparency, here are all of the comments, including deleted ones, in the original order:

> [image: comments]

As usual in these cases, the "comments are transient/ephemeral and can be deleted at any time" response that you tend to get on Meta is [partially true](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), but mostly a cop-out. These comments weren't deleted because comments are ephemeral. These comments were deleted because they were meaningless (in that they conveyed no useful information) and obsolete (in that they'd been replaced by a more meaningful comment that just happened to have been left by you, but could just as well have been left by anyone).

Comment: My comment that was not deleted did not make my first comment redundant. I carefully used distinct terms "issue" and "question". Issue is something the OP has come up with, and that was partially written. I commented that it was not clear. On the other hand, a question is something that should be addressed to other users like me. The OP had not written a question to use anywhere, and that was what I was asking in the comment that was deleted. They are distinct things.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am not asking you a question in the comment here. I am claiming that you are wrong.

Comment: @sawa: That "distinction" is just not relevant, particularly on the question at hand. First, the question doesn't need to be stated because it is *obvious*: the OP's first sentence says that he needs to do X. Therefore, his question is "how do I do X?" I don't see a need to have them repeat that. Second, even if that were not the case, any "issue" that the OP comes up is what they're asking about. That is, their question.

Comment: @sawa Best not to [intentionally vandalize](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/381891/4) posts (they'll just be rolled back anyway)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I wanted to check if the moderators were on a vacation since my flag (reported a few days ago) has not been taken care of.

Comment: @sawa Please stop vandalizing the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Comments are transient. Those specific comments were removed by a moderator due to a flag.

Comment: Do you know the reason?

Comment: *due to a flag* ...

Comment: @sawa now that we have the full story and all the comments: do you have a reason why they should have been kept? Looking at Cody's answer, I would agree wholeheartedly that the right thing was to delete them

Comment: @Patrice I just wrote in a comment to Cody's answer that Cody misinterpreted my comments to the question on the main site. By "question", I did not mean "issue". I meant different things. The question has not been written at all by the OP, and it still makes sense to ask for it. On the other hand, the OP's issue was partially written and unclear, and I was asking for that too.

Comment: @sawa that is splitting hairs to a degree that seems pointless to all involved in my honest opinion. And I would say that since your Stack overflow post is usually you asking a question about an issue.... I'd say the distinction is really just a pedantic point and not needed... But again that's my opinion here, this is clearly subjective. I just personally see no need to make that distinction, ever.

Comment: I actually didn't notice on first glance that OP was asking about their own comments that were deleted (I had someone came to the conclusion that OP is the OP of the question), and so didn't provide details. My apologies. Cody's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm French. And I appreciate people's comments on my grammar.

In the past, I had linked to grammatical rules in a comment or edit description.
Or comment stating that my sentence makes no sense.
They never felt Rude or not ok.

While we are on SO to solve a programming issue, it's always great to learn new things.
And we do appreciate the feedback.

That's the 3rd time today I was able to know someone's nationality just by reading some "broken" English.
So I think that I share enough with them that my reading of your comment may help.

Now let's talk about those comment of yours.
I would have taken them quite personally and would have flagged them as rude.
The repetition of the same question gives me a weird feeling.
My reading of grammatical rules changes after reading all the comment twice.
Capital letter and space before punctuation feels a lot more aggressive than they were.

Comment: Addendum: _This part is in a comment as I can formulate it_. This is only my interpretation and picture I have. It feels like a kid repeating "Are you ok?". The fact that from the outside perspective those comment trigger notification and were posted the deleted an reposted. Consolidate the impression of an annoying kid. Once again, I'm not saying that you are one. It's only the impression I had. I have no better picture to illustrate it.