# Can I answer questions even though I am not a native English speaker?

Tags: support, answers, english

I am mostly active on a non-English programming site on Stack Exchange, but I am interested in both English and Stack Overflow, so I read English sites. I can read English questions, and I often know the answers too, but I am not very fluent in English.

I would like to ask if I can answer your questions, even though my English is not fluent?

Comment: Terminology.
I don't understand the differentiation of American languages very well, but sometimes I see unfamiliar words that don't get translated even with a translator, so I thought it was some kind of technical term used only by programmers.

Comment: There's some nice advice [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362) for non-native English speakers. While it's mostly targeted at *asking* questions, a lot of the advice about grammar applies to answering questions as well, and is worth reading.

Comment: I would guess that most people here are not native English speakers, and especially not native American English speakers. In whatever way you created this meta post – be it your own English skills, a translator tool, or another way – it uses perfectly adequate English.

Comment: In my experience, people who say "my English is not fluent" are being way too modest. I would worry if you had said "I don't English very good", but instead you explained yourself like a champion. Give yourself some credit :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can.

As long as you put effort into the quality of your answers, a few grammatical errors won't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. There aren't any restrictions on what an answer should contain as long it is somewhat related to the question and written using English words.

If you really want answers to be understood, please read the table of content for specification of the language(s) you plan to answer questions for and use the right words:

- "cycles" belong to graph theory when most computer languages have "loops"
- there are plenty "attributes" in programming, but functions use "variables" to store intermediate values
- Pascal has "procedures", but it is very unlikely the language you'd pick to answer questions in have them even if "functions" and "methods" are the same thing
- You "return" value from methods even if you did not take it in the first place
- "process", "thread", "task", "fiber", "coroutine" may or may not mean the same or different things or mean anything at all in the programming language/framework of your choice.

Comment: A cycle, in the context of programming, is a clock tick of the system clock.

Answer (score -3):

As you are asking a question, you need only that much of English to understand others' questions and to make them understand your answers.

Comment: Yes, but it must still be comprehensible.

Comment: *What* makes it so difficult to include [articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles) (definite or indefinite) and information about singular or plural?