# Is this a bad question? and Why?

Tags: discussion

This is the question that get closed: [How should I set interface property with gdbus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77499778/8578922)

I think I have described the question in details, just want to known why it's not good for SO.

Comment: You have at least 3, maybe 4, questions there so it's way too broad. In addition, it breaks down to a *gimme de codez* request with no, apparent, attempt at resolving this for yourself.

Comment: Considering there is a close reason on your post saying it's unfocused and needs one question, not 3.... Why do you think it's a good question, by the standards of Stack?

Comment: I attempted to fix the question, but as I am not an expert in this technology, I can't say if the listed questions are actually the same question or 3 separate ones.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but I think it might have removed information about what answer it prefers (which is an example and if possible, explain the details about the related parts). From my experience, to ask a question, you should provide accurate and enough info to describe it, if possible focus on the more specific part (which is the three puzzles of the list), it's not independent question, a question can always be split into several smaller ones, and they together make the question explicit. From what I see, SO seems to judge the case by the way it expresses rather than the meaning

Comment: I don't get what makes you think the question does "provide accurate and enough info" or "focus on the more specific part (which is the three puzzles of the list)". The "puzzles" are all distinct questions in their own right, with little overlap of potential answers, and they come in at not even a full sentence each. The first is a text-book definition of *lacking* focus, and it's hard to see enough detail there either. Can you please [edit] this meta-question to provide reasoning and not fall into the same trap as the main-question?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I wrote the words in a native manner that cause any distinction, if it does, I'm sorry, and please tell. I'm not a native English speaker, but basically, I think the listed puzzles clearly express the main problem when I tried to set a property of the interface with gio bus, which is the question I'm trying to solve. As for whether it's distinct question or not, I can't just persuade anyone to believe that, but if someone know the answer, he might understand why I list the puzzles there.

Comment: I've rolled back your question to the edit Dharman had made since I felt it was better. A "How to" question is always better than "Are there any examples", etc. Also I am not an SME on that topic but it very much looks to me like those 3 are different (maybe somewhat related) questions.

Comment: But from my point of view, to ask the question again in the content is unnecessary, the title itself is already there. And as said, the original version of the question indicate what kind of answer or help it want most, so that if there is anyone to response, he can know that.

Comment: “But from my point of view, to ask the question again in the content is unnecessary, the title itself is already there.” - Some believe that the title should be descriptive not a question, and the body of the question, contains an explicit question. The question isn’t being well received currently so something has to change

Comment: "From what I see, SO seems to judge the case by the way it expresses rather than the meaning" People can not understand the meaning due to the way it is expressed, these two are connected, and seems you are not aware of that.

Comment: @gnat that's not very helpful. While I don't really know what a DBus is or what `gdbus` is, it seems pretty clear that there's one specific problem that OP is trying to solve, and that it should therefore be possible to focus the question on the important part, and that it wouldn't make sense to try to turn each bullet point into a separate question.

Comment: Note that there is no incentive to revisit and reappraise a question built into the system, so once a question gets a downvote, it's often stuck with it no matter how much the question is improved later. You are primarily counting on future visitors providing upvotes to bring the question back into the black.

Comment: Whether the question get reopened is not the key point, it is more a discussion to help understand why the question is bad for SO and how the reviewers read questions.

Comment: @giskard *"From what I see, SO seems to judge the case by the way it expresses rather than the meaning"* - Correct.  A side effect of there being thousands of questions asked a day and a large portion of those going into review queues; people close fast, not well. If it looks like it breaks an obvious rule, you can expect closure. Barring knowing the rules from memory, the easiest quick hack is to open another (open) question, click flag and then choose the "needs improvement" option. There you see the close reasons so you can vet your questions against that list.

Answer (score 12):

I will consider this version of the question:

```
I'm really puzzled about the Gio dbus's API design:

- what's the destination of `g_dbus_proxy_set_cached_property`
- how to flush the updated cached property to the server side
- why there is no direct `set_property()` or `get_property()`

Finally, I have to fallback to set property directly with the underlying dbus call. I think this is not what it should be.

Is there anyone willing to provide an example to set interface property with [gdbus proxy][1],
and if possible, explain any of the puzzles above, it will helps a lot

  [1]: https://docs.gtk.org/gio/class.DBusProxy.html
```

Here are some problems that should be fixed to ask the question properly.

- If you need to write code in a specific programming language in order to solve the problem, **please use the tag for that programming language**. Most of the `gdbus` questions I see are about using a command-line program named `gdbus` - not about the programmatic API. Very often, a similar API is made available for the same programming tool in many programming languages. A lot of the time, it will matter a lot which programming language you want to use.
- When we talk about "distinct" questions on Meta, what we mean is: could it make sense to write a separate post for each question, and get separate answers on each? We do not care if you need every answer in order to complete the task, because Stack Overflow is not about your task, it is about answering questions.

  It can sometimes be okay to put more than one question in the same post, if they can't be answered separately. Sometimes it wouldn't make sense to answer one without also answering the other. But it should be obvious that this is the case.

  It's basically never a good idea to write questions in a bulleted list. If the questions really do belong in the same post, it will make more sense to use no special formatting.
- Remember that we can't see your computer screen. Experts will know what the terms mean, and how to solve a lot of difficult problems, but they can't see what you're trying to do. Even if something is obvious to you and you think it should be obvious to an expert, it's better to be explicit.

  There are some fine points [of English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362) that can make it hard to understand technical ideas. I don't know the technology you are using. When I read "an example to set interface property with gdbus proxy", I get confused:

  - Does "interface" mean what kind of property it is? Or is `interface` the *name* of the property?
  - Does the proxy itself have the property?
  - Or is the proxy a tool that you use, to set that property for something else? In that case, *what is the "something else"*?

  The grammar is only a little bit wrong, but it's enough to help cause those problems.
- Questions should be *about* the problem, not about *you*. If you use "I" or "me" in a question, it should be to explain things that you tried to do or things that you saw happen. It should not be about how you feel about the problem.

  In particular, if you don't like the design of an API, we can't do anything about that. If you think you have a better idea about how it should work, maybe you can suggest it to the developers.

  "Why does it work this way" will almost always be a separate question, and it will usually not be suitable. We can't read the developers' minds, and we don't want a question to be an excuse to complain. Basically, we only take these questions when there's an objective way to answer them, e.g. quoting from a developer's blog.

  "Why *doesn't* it work *that* way" is even worse, because there is only one way it does work and countless other ways it could work. If you ever had to write code for the public to use, you should understand that you can't make everyone happy.

---

I guess that the main point of the question is how to set the property. I guess that "flush the updated cached property to the server side" makes sense as part of that question. I guess that `g_dbus_proxy_set_cached_property` (which I also see in that documentation) is something you tried using in order to solve the same problem.

So in my opinion, the question should look more like (I put some comments in between `<>` for things that I can't fix by myself):

```
I'm trying to use a [`GDBusProxy`](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/class.DBusProxy.html)
to set an interface property <or, "I'm trying to set the `interface` property
of a `GDBusProxy`", or whatever else is actually correct>.

The only way I found was to set the property directly with the underlying
`dbus` call, like so:

<show the code you used, if it works and it's short>

Is there a simpler way to set the property and make sure that the cached
property is flushed to the server side? I found 
[`g_dbus_proxy_set_cached_property`](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/method.DBusProxy.set_cached_property.html),
but it seems to only work on the client side.

<Is that right? I can't understand "what's the destination". If you mean that
you don't know if it flushed to the server side, then *you should try to check
this* before posting. If you don't know how to check if the output is correct,
then it is not possible to ask a suitable question.>
```

But I can't write it for you, because I don't know the technology well enough.

*Most* "how do I do this?" questions should not have a code example, because the point is to explain the solution, and not to look for problems in the code. But if you have something that works already, it can help to show us, so that we understand what you tried, why there's still a question, and how you want to improve the code.

I prefer to use inline links, but it doesn't really matter.